# definition of chi-square statistic

Tags: chi-squared-test

The chi-squared statistic is defined as 
\begin{equation}
\chi^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{(O_{i} - E_{i})^{2}}{E_{i}}
\end{equation}
The $O_{i}$ is observed value and $E_{i}$ is expected value.

But it seems that sometimes the statistic is defined differently as 
\begin{equation}
\chi^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{(O_{i} - E_{i})^{2}}{{\sigma_{i}}^{2}}
\end{equation}
The $\sigma_{i}^{2}$ is variance. I found this definition in this [Wikipedia page for reduced chi-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_chi-squared_statistic)

Are both of them called "chi-squared statistic"? When do you need the former and when do you need the latter?

Comment: As currently posted, neither is a chi-squared statistic. numerator needs to be squared.

Comment: @BruceET I'm sorry that I missed it. The formulas are corrected now.

Comment: Both are chi-squared statistics.  It is important for readers to consult that Wikipedia page on "reduced chi-square" because it uses nonstandard notation: "$\sigma_i^2$" is an (unbiased) *estimate* of variance, not a model parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding there are different types of chi-squared statistic. You can use the first formula to calculate the chi-squared test statistic as in [Pearson's test independence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) while the second formula is applied in [goodness of fit statistic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_chi-squared_statistic) tests. So it depends on the situation what formula you use.

Comment: In light of the edit that was made to the question, this answer is not correct: it will help to read the referenced Wikipedia article, which makes it clear the second statistic is the one that appears in goodness-of-fit tests.

Comment: Thank you. I adjusted the answer to the edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The latter definition is the general definition of the chi-square statistic. The former definition is for a special case where the parameter $\theta$ is Poisson distributed. Note that in a Poisson distribution expected value is the same as variance.